# Leave Site? changes you made may not be saved error in SP List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am getting error like the "Leave site? changes you made may not be saved" popup in Sharepoint list AllItems.aspx view, whenever I try to go to other pages from that view, this alert keeps on prompting.

in other lists it's not causing, any solution to avoid this error?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: So are you editing the list? Would you like to provide a screenshot on the list when you try to leave?

Comment: No i am not editing the list, when ever i try to navigate to Site Settings , it shows this error. this is a modern experience list

Comment: So it happens whenever you try to go to other page via navigation links? Have you ever customized the list? If you create a new list from this list, will this issue occur ? And in modern experience, we may not have site sittings link in the list view, are you going to site contents?

Comment: we have View all site settings under site information to navigate to site settings page. I am navigating to that link

Comment: Did you edit the list view from modern experience and then trying to navigate to site settings? If yes --> save the view using "Save view as" option from view selector dropdown at top right corner.

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
No i am not editing the list view, but this issue is persists for this issue alone. don't know where it's went wrong